# rails how to place checkbox before label on collection checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, checkbox, label

Using this code:

```
  - @contacts.each do |contact|
    = label_tag "contact[#{contact.id}]", contact.slug
    = check_box_tag "contact[#{contact.id}]", contact.id
    .clear
```

Results in:

```
  <label for="contact_1">Avalon3323</label>
                    <input id="contact_1" name="contact[1]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                    <div class='clear'></div>
                    <label for="contact_2">doutzen</label>
                    <input id="contact_2" name="contact[2]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
                    <div class='clear'></div>
                    <label for="contact_3">jannie6674</label>
```

Which seems okay according to the documentation.

Still the label is positioned before the checkbox.
Does one have to fix this with CSS? Shouldn't the html order be correctly by itself?

Comment: There is no "correct order". Either swap your tags around, or use CSS. Both approaches are valid.

Comment: yes ive swapped them to no avail.

Comment: Use simple_form and my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053863/simple-form-how-to-make-accept-terms-checkbox-inline/13054234#13054234

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to swap code?

```
= check_box_tag "contact[#{contact.id}]", contact.id
= label_tag "contact[#{contact.id}]", contact.slug
```