# Simple_form how to make accept terms checkbox inline

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

```
<p><%= f.input :terms, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :boolean_style => :inline %> 
Accept <%= link_to "Terms of use", terms_path,:remote => true %> 
and <%=link_to "privacy Policy", privacy_path, :remote => true%></p>
```

It ends up looking like this

[image]

What is the best way to line them up on the same line.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a rather simple way:

```
<%= content_for(:the_links) do %>
    Accept <%= link_to "Terms of use", terms_path,:remote => true %> 
    and <%=link_to "privacy Policy", privacy_path, :remote => true%>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :terms, :as => :boolean, :label => content_for(:the_links)%> 
<% end%>
```

[image: the-non-styled-output]

Comment: nice use of content_for block :)

Comment: Hey, that's a great trick with the `content_for`. Very useful.

Comment: This only worked for me when I changed :label to :inline_label

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the checkbox and text are small enough to fit in one row inside the container, then set `display: inline;` or `float:left;`

Comment: display: inline doesn't work and float left works but it looks weird because my form is centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `wrapper_html` like this:

```
<p>
  <%= f.input :terms, 
            :as => :boolean, 
            :label => false, 
            :boolean_style => :inline,     
            :wrapper_html => { :style => 'display: inline' } 
  %> 
  Accept <%= link_to "Terms of use", terms_path,:remote => true %> 
  and <%=link_to "privacy Policy", privacy_path, :remote => true%>
</p>
```