# Rails App not Recognizing Field Acceptance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validates acceptance always failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746710/validates-acceptance-always-failing)

I'm using the [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gems in my Rails 3.2 app.  In the user registration view, I have added a check box that is for user to check for agreeing to the Terms of Use for the app.  However, now, even when it is checked, the code doesn't realize that it's checked, so it's giving the error message that this required field is not accepted.

It may have to do with me implementing the `content_for` code in the form based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053863/simple-form-how-to-make-accept-terms-checkbox-inline).

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  validates :agree_to_terms, :acceptance => true
end
```

The view:

```
<%= content_for(:the_links) do %>
  I agree to the <%= link_to "Terms of Service", terms_path,:remote => true %> 
  and <%=link_to "Privacy Policy", privacy_path, :remote => true%>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :agree_to_terms, :as => :boolean, :inline_label => content_for(:the_links), :label => false %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", :class =>"btn btn-success btn-large" %>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the code doesn't realize that it's checked"? What are being passed to the controller in the params var?

Comment: Did you create the field in the database table or is it just transient? It matters, having the field exist changes the way the value is cast.

Comment: @noodl that solved my issue!  if you want, post an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks!